# How to Use the Jquery Number Spinner to Update Quantity in DB?

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I’m new to JQuery/JavaScript/Ajax as well as Symfony2 & PHP.

I’m building a simple Shopping Cart and I want to the users to be able to control the quantity of a product they added in their cart using the JQuery Spinner (https://jqueryui.com/spinner/).

Being new, I could really use some help with how to do this.

All of my attempts have failed and I’m just struggling.

HTML/Twig:

```
        <tbody>
        {% for key, product in quantity %}  
                <tr>
                    {{ dump(key) }}
                    <td>{{ product.product }}</td> <!--Product--> 
                    <td>
                        <input class="spinner" value="{{ product.quantity }}" style="width:30px">
                    </td> <!--Quantity-->
                    <td>${{ product.product.price|default('') }}</td> <!--Price-->   
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ path('product_remove', {'id': key }) }}">
                            <button name="REMOVE" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="removeButton">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </td><!--Remove--> 
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}      
        </tbody>
    </table> <!--top table-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".spinner").spinner();
</script>
```

Product Controller (Where I set Quantity…):

```
    $quantity = new Quantity();

    if (is_null($cart) || $cart->getSubmitted(true)) {
        $cart = new UserCart();
    }

    $cart->setTimestamp(new \DateTime()); // Set Time Product was Added 
    $quantity->setQuantity(1);   // Set Quantity Purchased
    $cart->setSubmitted(false); // Set Submitted
    $cart->setUser($this->getUser());  // Sets the User ONCE
    $cart->addQuantity($quantity);    //  Add Quantity ONCE
    $quantity->setUserCart($cart);   //   Create a UserCart ONCE
    $quantity->setProduct($product); // Sets the Product to Quantity Association ONCE
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->persist($cart);
    $em->persist($quantity); 
    $em->flush();
    $this->addFlash('notice', 'The product: '.$product->getName().' has been added to the cart!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to handle the `change` event on the spinner. When it's updated, fire off a request to the database to update it.

Replace the `url` below with your URL.

```
$('input.spinner').on('change', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/update/my/product/quantity',
        method: 'POST',
        data : {
            quantity: $this.val()
        }
    }).done(function(resp){
        console.log('success', resp);
    }).error(function(err){
        console.log('error', resp);
    });
});
```

Handle the product quantity coming over in `$_POST['quantity']` manually and update the `cart` accordingly.

The logic to handle this inside of your Symphony controller is out of the scope because it's too broad and there's not enough information to give definitive directions.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but how do I find/know my url for updating quantity? is it the url in my browser?

Comment: @user6104636 Yep - Whichever page you determine. You create the Routes to handle the data yourself, so wherever you need it togo.